# Is the product of two orthogonally diagonalizable matrices still orthogonally diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Let $S$ and $T$ be two orthogonally diagonalizable matrices with $ST=TS$. Then is $ST$ still orthogonally diagonalizable?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

No. A real matrix is orthogonally diagonalisable if and only if it is symmetric. If $S$ and $T$ are symmetric, $ST$ is symmetric if and only if $ST=TS$. So, any pair of symmetric matrices $S$ and $T$ such that $ST\ne TS$ can serve as a counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

$A\in{ \mathbb{M}}_n(\mathbb{C})$  orthogonaly diagonalisable by a unitary $U$   is equivalent to $A$ is normal. The classic fact is that the product of two normal matrices is not normal, here since $ST=TS$ with $S$ and $T$ normal they are simultaneously diagonalisable with a unitary matrix $U$ , $TS$ is normal.